# Subfolders in /usr/local/lib?

Tags: c, cmake, shared-libraries

I'm developing a simple C shared library for my university using Cmake.
At the moment I'm developing the install procedure of my *.so and my .*h files.

Where should I put the so and the header files when the user runs the famous `sudo make install`?
From what I understand:

1. I shouldn't put them in `/usr/lib` and `/usr/include` since those folders are reserved for distribution packages;
2. I shouldn't put them in `/lib` and `/include` since those folders are reserved for OS boot packages;

That leaves me with `usr/local/lib` and `/usr/local/include`. However I can't decide whether or not I should put my files in a subfolder:

1. Putting the files directly inside `usr/local/lib` and `/usr/local/include` will make them directly available in the system but they will remain unorganized with all the other files in the folders. More disturbing fact is that if someone installs another shared library whose header has the same name of mine, unknown behaviours may happen;
2. Putting the files in a subfolder (`/usr/local/lib/myAwesomeProject/` and `/usr/local/include/myAwesomeProject`) will avoid the behaviours above, but will prevent the system to automatically detect my libraries (from what I understand the system automatically looks for include and library only in specific directories **non-recursively**): so if the system looks into `/usr/local/include`, my includes won't be found because of the subfolder!

To help you, here's my system:

- OS system: Ubuntu 16.4 (64 bit virtualized on Windows 10 64-bit);
- CPU (not that I think is useful): Intel® Core™ i5-3230M CPU @ 2.60GHz × 2;

Thanks for any kind reply!

Comment: Why not install in `/opt`? The `/opt` folder is meant for additional software which is not installed via standard means that is through a package manager or similar. You can then use `set(CMAKE_MODULE_PATH ${CMAKE_MODULE_PATH} <dir_in_opt_where_your_lib_is>)` inside a project which uses the library. As for the structure of the installation folder - it really depends on what the library's structure is. Especially for libs that use C++ templates (where the library is actually inside the header files) it's not uncommon to not have an include.

Comment: I always thought that "make install" was considered "standard means": am I wrong? As for the CMAKE_MODULE_PATH: I can certainly use that approach, but that does not defeat the purpose of having common directories where the system automatically looks fro *.so and *.h?

Comment: This question is unrelated to both C and CMake. Probably even unrelated to programming. Regarding CMake: the install prefix can be changed, but /usr/bin et al. is a sane default choice.

Comment: I can agree that the question is unrelated to both C and CMake (I put them as labels only to give context): this question is all about deployment. As for the "/usr/bin" location: I understand even CMake set it as default choice when perfoming "sudo make install" (if the user didn't add anything in ./configure phase)... but what about the "headers" conflicts? Is just me being too paranoid?

Comment: 1. Approaches for libraries and headers locations could be different: you should place **library directly** into `/usr/local/lib` (otherwise linker will unable to find them) but may place **headers under subfolder** of `/usr/local/include` (so them will not be mixed with headers from other libraries). 2. The question itsels is *opinion-based*, as there is **no universal rule** about installing locations. As a simple but widely used approach you may use install directories from [GNUInstallDirs](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/module/GNUInstallDirs.html) CMake module.

Comment: @Tsyvarev: I thought this process was well-standardized... i didn't realize it was actually a very debatable topic. I think your comment is at the moment the most clarifying one. +1 also citing the standard: it always helps. If you can make your comment an answer I will +1 it. (After some days, if no other approaches are posted, I will mark the answer as accepted)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Approaches for libraries and headers locations could be different: you should place **library directly** into `/usr/local/lib` (otherwise linker will unable to find them) but may place **headers under subfolder** of `/usr/local/include` (so them will not be mixed with headers from other libraries).
2. The question itsels is *opinion-based*, as there is **no universal rule** about installing locations. As a simple but widely used approach you may use install directories from [GNUInstallDirs](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/module/GNUInstallDirs.html) CMake module.

– Tsyvarev